# How stop save data in the database if the value is undefined in MySQL

Tags: javascript

I want to stop save data in the database if the value is undefined in MySQL. For doing that I have done the following things.

```
const query = `insert into prod (description, rate) values ("${req.body.des}", "${(req.body.cur_rate == 'undefined' ? ' ' : req.body.cur_rate)}");`
```

I tried above if `rate` is `undefined` in the database it should save as space. But the above try is not successful. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing it with the *string* `'undefined'`, which is not `undefined`.  Fortunately, `undefined` is ["falsy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) so you don't actually need the comparison.  This expression should work just as well:

```
req.body.cur_rate ? req.body.cur_rate : ' '
```

So:

```
const query = `insert into prod (description, rate) values ("${req.body.des}", "${(req.body.cur_rate ? req.body.cur_rate : ' ')}");`
```

Or even simpler, you can short-circuit a logical `||` and allow the expression to return the first ["truthy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value:

```
req.body.cur_rate || ' '
```

So:

```
const query = `insert into prod (description, rate) values ("${req.body.des}", "${(req.body.cur_rate || ' ')}");`
```